# Unknown Column in 'having clause' #1054 MS access front end to MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which fails with the following `ODBC - call failed" error (Unknown Column 'sale_inv_detail.qty' in 'having clause' #1054)`.

```
SELECT sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq FROM (SELECT sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq, Sum([cust_cash_alloc]![cash_value]) AS Expr2, ([qty]*[price_net]) AS Expr1
FROM cust_cash_alloc RIGHT JOIN sale_inv_detail ON cust_cash_alloc.sales_inv_detail_seq = sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq
GROUP BY sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq, ([qty]*[price_net]) )
WHERE Expr1>Expr2 ;
```

The query does not report an error if the `WHERE clause` contains only `Expr1` or `Expr2`.

```
For example : Expr1>1
```

I am slightly perplexed as I do not have a HAVING clause.
If I recast the query to use a HAVING clause and not a WHERE clause then I still have the same error when the condition depends upon two expressions (as described above). The query recast with HAVING (and still reporting the same error) is:

```
SELECT sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq
FROM (SELECT sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq, Sum([cust_cash_alloc]![cash_value]) AS Expr2, ([qty]*[price_net]) AS Expr1 
FROM cust_cash_alloc RIGHT JOIN sale_inv_detail ON cust_cash_alloc.sales_inv_detail_seq = sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq 
GROUP BY sale_inv_detail.sale_inv_detail_seq, ([qty]*[price_net]) 
HAVING Sum([cust_cash_alloc]![cash_value])>([qty]*[price_net])  )  ;
```

A HAVING clause: `HAVING 1>([qty]*[price_net])` or `HAVING Sum([cust_cash_alloc]![cash_value])>1` does not report an error (but is not what I want)

Comment: You should have one, because your expressions are the result of aggregate functions. You can't use alias names in the WHERE clause but you can in the HAVING clasue. Btw. the order of the clauses is FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING and these clauses can't be interchanged. Maybe this is the cause for the error message.

Comment: Thank you VMai. I have edited the original post to show the equivalent use of HAVING which still reports the same error.